# Key Chain Access issue when app distribute through MDM

Tags: objective-c, iphone, keychain, mdm

In our [ipad](/questions/tagged/ipad) application user has to enter his details for registration. After user enter his details we save those details in the Device's [keychain](/questions/tagged/keychain). So next time user launched the app user can use the app without registering again. Since we save it in the [keychain](/questions/tagged/keychain) even the app reinstall by deleting is also works fine.

To write to key chain we use [sskeychain](/questions/tagged/sskeychain) class as most developer do. This feature is working properly in devices without any issue.

One of our client use their [symantec](/questions/tagged/symantec) ([unitymobile](/questions/tagged/unitymobile)) [mdm](/questions/tagged/mdm) to distribute this app to their users. But when user install it through the [mdm](/questions/tagged/mdm) app gives following error when saving data to the key chain.

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.samsoffes.sskeychain error
>   -34018.)"

Initially we thought this is due to one of the policies they have included. But no luck. Can some one please tell me what has happened here and how to solve this issue.

P.S.
Actually underlying error was this.
(OSStatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements)